# No alternative languages in Microsoft Translator v. 3.0 Detect JSON Response

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-translator

According to the [Microsoft Translator 3.0 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-detect) the JSON Response body for the Detect endpoint should contain the following property:

- alternatives: An array of other possible languages. Each element of the array is another object with the same properties listed above: language, score, isTranslationSupported and isTransliterationSupported.

Here is an example of a Request body from the [Translator Quickstart web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translator?tabs=python#detect-language):

```
[
    { "Text": "Ich würde wirklich gern Ihr Auto um den Block fahren ein paar Mal." }
]
```

And here is an expected Response body:

```
[
    {
        "alternatives": [
            {
                "isTranslationSupported": true,
                "isTransliterationSupported": false,
                "language": "nl",
                "score": 0.92
            },
            {
                "isTranslationSupported": true,
                "isTransliterationSupported": false,
                "language": "sk",
                "score": 0.77
            }
        ],
        "isTranslationSupported": true,
        "isTransliterationSupported": false,
        "language": "de",
        "score": 1.0
    }
]
```

However, when I use the same Request body in my language detection endpoint, I only get one language with the score of 1.0:

```
import requests, uuid, json

# Add your subscription key and endpoint
subscription_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com"

# Add your location, also known as region. The default is global.
# This is required if using a Cognitive Services resource.
location = "global"

path = '/detect'
constructed_url = endpoint + path

params = {
'api-version': '3.0'
}
constructed_url = endpoint + path

headers = {
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': location,
'Content-type': 'application/json',
'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
'text': 'Ich würde wirklich gern Ihr Auto um den Block fahren ein paar Mal.'
}]

request = requests.post(constructed_url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

[
    {
        "isTranslationSupported": true,
        "isTransliterationSupported": false,
        "language": "de",
        "score": 1.0
    }
]
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I believe alternatives are provided only if detected. Your sentence may be unambiguously one language. Have you tried other sentences?

Comment: Yes, I tried some other sentences from the MS Docs with a few detected alternatives on their side as well as my own sentences, but I keep getting only one language with the score of 1.0 back.

Comment: Follow-up on this question on [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/76340).

Answer (score 0):

After tested, I have try to use nodejs, offical restapi, and C# language to test. Get same result. And I can debug it, find `Alternatives` is always null.

So I am sure offical document is not lastest.

Now the response you got is right. You can `submit feedback` in this page.

[image]